# Unipotent one-parameter subgroup and exponential map

Tags: lie-groups, dynamical-systems, lie-algebras

Let $E$ be a finite real dimensional vector space and $\{u_t\}_{t\in \mathbb R}$ be a unipotnent one-parameter subgroup of $GL(E)$, which means each $u_t$ is unipotent (the only eigenvalue is $1$) and $u_{s+t}=u_s \circ u_t$.

I wonder how to derive from the above information that $u_t$ must be of the form

$$u_t=\exp(t \eta),$$

where $\eta$ is a nilpotent transformation on $E$.

The key part is to find $\eta$ I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Write $A={d\over{dt}}_{t=0}u_t$, consider $f_t=exp(tA)$, $f_t$ and $u_t$ are solutions of the same OD and coincide at $0$, so they coincide. This implies in particular that $exp(A$ is unipotent and $A$ is nilpotent, otherwise $A$ has an eigenvalue eventually complex distinct of $0$.

Comment: what is the meaning of "eventually complex distinct of 1"?

Comment: If the eigenvalue $c$ is not $0$ then you can conjugate $A$ into an upper triangular matrix and that eigenvalue appears on the diagonal, $exp(c)$ is an eigenvalue of $exp(A)$ and $exp(A)$ is not unipotent.

Comment: $f_t$ you defined is the solution to $dy/dt = Ay$, $du_t /dt$ is quite unknown except for the value at $t=0$